# Htacess rewrite nao abre index

Tags: apache

Oi,
tenho esse `.htacess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(css|images|js|fonts) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ PDOClasses/Pages/checkurl.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ PDOClasses/Pages/checkurl.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)$ PDOClasses/Pages/checkurl.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)/$ PDOClasses/Pages/checkurl.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Não consigo acessar a `index.php` pois me joga pra `checkurl.php`
o que fiz de errado nas regras?

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer desta forma usando *RewriteRule* e inserindo `^(.*)$ /` acompanhado do `index.php`. Aí você pode adapta-lo.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Não funciona :(